# why does ld linker fail when compiling elf_i386 code

Tags: x86, mingw, linker-errors, ld, osdev

I am trying to make a simple OS and can't seem to get the linker working.
I tried to use the command:

```
ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel-entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
```

but it just responds with:

```
unrecognised emulation mode: elf_i386
```

I'm currently trying to run this on windows using MinGW and
i don't want to have to use wsl (windows subsystem for linux) becasue that won't work either.

to try and run this i ran:

```
gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
nasm assembly/kernel-entry.asm -f elf -o kernel-entry.o
ld -m elf_i386 -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 kernel-entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary
nasm assembly/mbr.asm -f bin -o mbr.bin
cat mbr.bin kernel.bin > os-image.bin
qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.bin
```

Comment: Because your MIngW `gcc` compiler and utilities like `ld` don't understand `ELF` file format. I'd recommend install an i386 or i686 ELF cross compiler. OS Development would be easier using Linux in WSL/WSL2. The other option is to use `-f win32` with nasm (instead of `-f elf32`) and `-mi386pe` with LD (instead of `-melf_i386`) . Using Windows tool chains for OS development can be problematic and there have been issues generating proper binaries for a kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ld --help` and look for the line starting with `supported emulations:`.

It will list the emulations that are supported in the `ld` that you're using.

Since MinGW/MinGW-w64 targets Windows which uses COFF/PE format instead of ELF there is a big chance your gcc+binutils won't support the platform you are trying to target.

The solution would be to get gcc+binutils that does support your emulation/target platdorm, either by building it yourself or somehow finding a prebuilt version that does work.

Or you could try cross-compiling from Linux. On my Debian Linux I see `ld --help` returns:

```
supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386p
```

Answer (score 0):

> to try and run this  ran:
>
> ```
> gcc -m32 [...]
> [...]
> ld [...]
> ```

**In almost all cases, you never ever want to call `ld` by hand.** Use `gcc`  instead.

This is bacause `gcc` is not a compiler. `gcc` is a driver program that calls sub-processes like compiler proper (`cc1` for C, `cc1plus` for C++, `lto1` for LTO byte-code), assembler (`as`) and linker (`collect2` and `ld`) depending on command line options.

For example, if the process includes linking like with

`gcc main.c -o main.exe`

`gcc` will finally call the linker with *many* options and libs that you don't want to add by hand.  To see the commands the triver is invoking, add `-v -Wl,-v` to the `gcc` options.  More specfically, in your case you want to link by means of something like

`gcc -m32 -o kernel.elf -Ttext 0x1000 kernel-entry.o kernel.o`

and then use `objcopy` to transform from ELF to other formats as needed. (Requesting non-default output formaty from `gcc` has issues back then, so better to is in a seperate step.

Moreover, you might want to add more options like `-nostdlib`, `-nostartfiles`, `nodefaultlibs`, set the entry point or whatever you might need.

I am not familir with the exact toolchain you are using. Are you trying to do some kind of cross-compilation? I.e. the machine / OS that hosts `gcc` is not that same like the one that will run the execuatable.  If that's the case, you need a proper cross-compiler, and `-m32` won't be enough.